# JOIN on varchar column with subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, join

i know that this is not the recommended way to `join` tables. But it's only relevant for one rarely used report for one person and i don't want to change my datamodel for it.

I have two tables `Model` and `SparePart` that are not directly linked with each other via foreign keys.

```
Model            SparePart
idModel          idSparePart
ModelName        SparePartDescription
                 Price
```

In special cases a model is also a sparepart(exchange unit). Then i need the price for this model from the `SparePart` table via its `SparePartDescription` column.

For example:

```
ModelName = C510
SparePartDescription = C510/Exchange Unit/Exch unit/Red
```

So i try to join both tables to get the price with following SQL:

```
SELECT m.idModel, m.ModelName, sp.Price, sp.SparePartDescription
FROM   modModel AS m INNER JOIN 
       tabSparePart AS sp ON m.ModelName =
       (SELECT TOP 1 LEFT(sp.SparePartDescription, CHARINDEX('/', sp.SparePartDescription) - 1)order by price desc)
WHERE  (CHARINDEX('/', sp.SparePartDescription) > 0) 
AND  (sp.fiSparePartCategory = 6)
ORDER BY m.ModelName, sp.SparePartDescription
```

But i get multiple records for one model:

```
idModel    ModelName   Price        SparePartDescription
569        C510        70,75        C510/Exchange Unit/Exch unit/Red
569        C510        70,75        C510/Exchange Unit/Latin/Generic/Black
569        C510        70,75        C510/Exchange Unit/Latin/Generic/Silver
433        C702        80,72        C702/Exchange Unit/Latin/Generic/Black
433        C702        NULL         C702/Exchange Unit/Latin/Generic/Cyan
433        C702        80,72        C702/Exchange Unit/Orange Global/Black
```

I only want to select one record if there are multiple spareparts with matching SparePartDescription.

Comment: the spareparts desc dont match though....

Comment: How should the choice be made as to which sparepart is the 'correct' single record?

Comment: @Dems: I thought my subquery in the join condition would emphasize my priority(`Price DESC`).

Comment: @TimSchmelter is there a preferencial order of spare parts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the ROW_NUMBER function.  It guarantees that you'll only get one of each item as defined in the PARTITION BY clause.

```
SELECT a.idModel, a.ModelName, Price, SparePartDescription
FROM modModel a
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT m.idModel, m.ModelName, sp.Price, sp.SparePartDescription
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY m.idModel, m.ModelName ORDER BY sp.price DESC) AS r
    FROM   modModel AS m 
    INNER JOIN tabSparePart AS sp 
        ON m.ModelName = LEFT(sp.SparePartDescription, CHARINDEX('/', sp.SparePartDescription) - 1)
    WHERE  (CHARINDEX('/', sp.SparePartDescription) > 0) 
        AND  (sp.fiSparePartCategory = 6)
) b
    ON a.idModel = b.idModel
    AND b.r = 1
ORDER BY ModelName, SparePartDescription
```

Comment: Why DENSE_RANK()?  This can and will cause multiple parts with the same price to appear as r = 1, so still allowing 1:many in the final results.  (Also, you need `Price DESC` rather than ascending.)

Comment: Good call with the price DESC.  ROW_NUMBER would then probably be a better call as well.  Updating answer.

Comment: @Norla: So you mean instaed of `DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY...` i should try `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY...`? It seems to work, but i need also the records from `modModel` that don't have a matching record in `tabSparePart`. I've tried `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` without success.

Comment: @Norla: now yours is the fastest approach that also lists the non-matching records. Changing the accepted answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Sql Server 2005 and better introduced the 'APPLY' operator which allows you to join against a subquery... Try this.

```
SELECT m.idModel, m.ModelName, sp.Price, sp.SparePartDescription
FROM   modModel AS m 
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT TOP 1 * FROM tabSparePart
  WHERE m.ModelName = 
   LEFT(SparePartDescription, LEN(ModelName)) 
  ORDER BY Price DESC
) sp
WHERE  (sp.fiSparePartCategory = 6)
ORDER BY m.ModelName, sp.SparePartDescription
```

It inner joins the 'modModel' table with the subquery 'only the top one matching tabSparePart'.

You can also use OUTER APPLY which will emulate a LEFT JOIN on the subquery.  Documentation is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).

Comment: +1 just because I *love* APPLY.  Out of everything that appeared in 2005, I think I love it the most.  I'd stroke it like a cat if I could.

Comment: @Matt: Thanks. I've edited your answer because there was a closing bracket missing. But i still get a `nvalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function`. I think this is because of the missing `WHERE  (CHARINDEX('/', sp.SparePartDescription) > 0)` in the subselect, isn't it?

Comment: @TimSchmelter - I agree.  The error is for descriptions without an `/` in them.  Causing a length param of -1.  Move the `> 0` WHERE clause inside the CROSS APPLY to try to correct this (And probably the `Category = 6` condition too.)  - This will only work IF the `> 0` clause is first AND the optimiser shortcuts the conditions, and doesn't execute the subsequent conditions if there is no `/` in the description.

Comment: Yeah, Thanks for the edits... It looks like you guys have got it... I love me some CROSS APPLY... that and CTE's have revolutionized SQL in my opinion. :)

Comment: @TimSchmelter - If moving that condition inside the APPLY does not work, `LEFT(sp_innner.SparePartDescription, LEN(m.ModelName)) = m.ModelName` should work instead of the existing join condition.

Comment: @Dems: Yes, the `LEN` approach is indeed simpler. Edited @Matt's answer accordingly.

Comment: @Dems: strangely the `len-approach` is slower than the `charindex-approach`, even if the second needs an additional check for the existense of the `/` in the where-clause.

Answer (score 1):

First, your join condition can be simplified some, and then you can use ROW_NUMBER() to specify some kind of order to your results, allowing the first result (per model) to be selected.  I also changed it to a LEFT JOIN in case there was no match.  If that is not required, it's simple to change back to an INNER JOIN :)

```
WITH
  ranked_results AS
(
  SELECT
    m.idModel, m.ModelName, sp.Price, sp.SparePartDescription,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY m.idModel ORDER BY sp.Price DESC) AS rank
  FROM
    modModel       AS m
  LEFT JOIN 
    tabSparePart   AS sp
      ON  LEFT(sp.SparePartDescription, LEN(m.ModelName)) = m.ModelName
      AND (CHARINDEX('/', sp.SparePartDescription) > 0) 
      AND (sp.fiSparePartCategory = 6)
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  ranked_results
WHERE
  rank = 1
ORDER BY
  ModelName,
  SparePartDescription
```

@MattMurrell's answer just appeared while I was typing this.  One difference here is that the selection criteria is being applied to the whole set, rather than separately in the CROSS APPLY.  This *may* have a performance benefit, you'd have to try and see.  CROSS APPLY with inline functions *is* normally more performant that correlated sub-queries, so I can't *predict* which is faster.

Comment: Thanks. But i get an exception: `ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified`. If there are multiple records i want to select that one with highest `Price`(Price DESC).

Comment: My Bad, it should move to the outer query.

Comment: By far the fastest approach apart from @Nola's, but his lists only the models that have matching spareparts.

Comment: If i replace your `LEN(m.ModelName)` with the charindex-approach it'll run much faster.

Comment: Accepted @Norlas answer not because its faster but because this query will be part of a greater one. The `with` statement is not so customizable as a subquery in my opinion.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - Without seeing the bigger query, you may be right.  But note that WITH does have a very powerful structure to simplify queries.  `WITH xxx AS (<query>), yyy AS (<query using xxx), zzz AS (<query using xxx AND yyy) <final query, using xxx, yyy and zzz>`.  This enables you to break down a large query into logical steps, and also to reuse those logical steps multiple times as necessary.  It's magic bullet to solve all consideration, but very often it is the most powerful, tidy, flexible and maintainable.  I'm glad you have an answer that works :)